# How and where to change date format of microba date picker

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner in Java programming and I am using Netbeans. I want to change the Date format of the Microba date picker to "dd-MMM-yy" and also remove the remaining fields. How to do these things?
Thank you.

Comment: Download the source, knock yourself out

Comment: Start by taking a look at the source for [`DatePicker`](https://github.com/tdbear/microba/blob/master/src/main/java/com/michaelbaranov/microba/calendar/DatePicker.java) - There are a number of constructors, one of which takes a `DateFormat`. If you don't know how to use `DateFormat`, then I recommend you take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), there are countless examples available to show you how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Since [Microba `DataPicker` is open source](https://github.com/tdbear/microba) you could just clone the repo and have a look at the source code for your self.

If you have a look at the [source code for the `DatePicker` class](https://github.com/tdbear/microba/blob/master/src/main/java/com/michaelbaranov/microba/calendar/DatePicker.java) you will notice a number constructors which you can use to customise the picker, several take a `DateFormat` class which you can use to modify the format of the date value.

If you don't know how to use `DateFormat`, then I recommend you take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), there are countless examples available to show you how to use it

As to remove elements, you'd have to look closer at the source code and make determinations on how best that might be achieved, since I'm not sure what fields you're talking about.